# How to tell excel automatically add value in a cell of a sheet when the value is added in another cell of another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have cells A1 and A2 in sheet1 with values 3, 4 respectively. I link the cell A1 and A2 to B1 and B2 in sheet2 respectively. I mean when A1 and A2 change, B1 and B2 change accordingly.

This is what I want to manipulate my spearsheet: When I add value 5 in cell A3 in sheet1, value 5 is also added in cell B3 in sheet2. 
Without filling `=A3` in B3 or using autofill, how can I do so?

Imagining that each time when you make a report you have to add a lot new cells -- A4 to  A100 --, that the number of cells is varied each time, and that you have a lot of corresponding sheets to sheet1 -- sheet2 to sheet100 -- you will find why I need your help.

Comment: @simoco It is not. Since the answer in the link can only work if I want the value of a cell is the same as value of corresponding cell in sheet1. For example A1's in sheet1 and sheet2 have the same value. I will not work if I want A1 in sheet 1 have the same value as B10 in sheet2, for example.

Comment: so, what have you tried for modifying code from previous Q to suit your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to your problem is to select the sheets on which you want the values to appear in corresponding cells by holding down the control key and clicking on sheet tab. So when you make an entry on Sheet1 in any cell  the same appears in the corresponding cell of another sheet (s) selected.